# Anaconda does not recognize updated package

Tags: python, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda (for the first time) on OSX 10.11.6, and things seem to work fine except that it does not recognize the update of `multiprocessing`. I was able to successfully update e.g., `scipy` and `IPython`, but somehow it doesn't work with `multiprocessing`.

If I run `conda update multiprocessing` it tells me that the latest version, `2.6.2.1`, is already installed (after running it for the first time of course). Indeed, the path

```
$ANACONDA_PATH/pkgs/multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocessing/
```

contains version `2.6.2.1`, but the version `(I)Python` is seeing (i.e., the output of `multiprocessing.__path__`) is located in

```
$ANACONDA_PATH/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/
```

whose `__init__.py` reads `__version__ = '0.70a1'`.

I tried

```
 conda remove multiprocessing
```

and it removes the new version. A second call does not find any packages to remove.

I'm sure I could copy the files from the former path to the latter and get the version I want, but surely that's not the way it's meant to be, and it would be quite annoying to have to do this for every other updated package.

Any help is much appreciated!

**Edit:**

After doing `conda remove multiprocessing` (one run was enough to then get a message `Error: no packages found to remove from environment: $ANACONDA_PATH`), I see the following output from `conda list`:

```
multiprocessing           2.6.2.1                   <pip>
```

There are several other packages that say `<pip>` in the third column; for all of those I can import the proper version. I then ran `pip uninstall multiprocessing` and the entry disappeared. Nevertheless I can still import multiprocessing v0.70a1 in an `IPython` session.

After all this trouble I just deleted the folder containing the old version and re-installed, and now I can import the latest version. I presume it's just anaconda looking in one folder before the other but it seems funny then that stuff gets installed into the low-priority folder.

Comment: Is this installation of anaconda your default python install?

Comment: yes, without having changed any configuration, `which python` returns `$ANACONDA_PATH/bin/python`

Comment: Can you try doing `conda remove multiprocessing` until it does not find any packages to remove as you have said, and then posting the relevant sections of `conda list`.